# Exercise 24(a) Chapter 3 Baby Rudin Proof Verification

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, cauchy-sequences

> Let $X$ be a metric space.
>
> (a) Call two Cauchy sequences $\left\{ p_n \right\}$, $\left\{ q_n \right\}$ in $X$ *equivalent* if $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} d \left( p_n, q_n \right) = 0.$$ Prove that this is an equivalence relation.

Can someone let me know if my proof for transitivity is correct?

Let $\{p_n\}, \{q_n\}, \{r_n\}$ be Cauchy sequences in $X$. Suppose $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} d \left( p_n, q_n \right) = 0 \textrm{ and } \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} d \left( q_n, r_n \right) = 0$. Let $\epsilon > 0$. Then, $\exists N_1, N_2 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{split}
        n \geq N_1 &\implies d(p_n, q_n) < \epsilon/2 \\
        n \geq N_2 &\implies d(q_n, r_n) < \epsilon/2 
    \end{split}
\end{equation*}
Pick $N = \max\{N_1, N_2\}$. Then, by the triangle inequality, $n \geq N$ implies
\begin{equation*}
  d(p_n, r_n)  \leq d(p_n, q_n) + d(q_n, r_n) < \epsilon
\end{equation*}
showing that $p_n \to r_n$ which means that$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} d \left(p_n, r_n \right) = 0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost. You claimed to have proved that $p_n\to r_n$, whatever that means. What you *did* prove was that $\lim_{n\to\infty}d(p_n,r_n)=0$, and that is what you were supposed to prove.

Comment: Oh, I see where I went wrong. BTW, I erroneously claimed that $p_n \to r_n$ not $p_n \to q_n$, no?

Comment: Right. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Would it be correct to say that I have shown that $d(d(p_n, r_n), 0) < \epsilon$ to make the result more clear?

Comment: As far as I am concerned, that makes your proof *less* clear.

Comment: But is it an accurate thing to say or is it incorrect?

Comment: Yes, but I surely would not write that.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I was just making sure that I completely understood what I had written.